# Excel Pivot Table: Group 'Count of Dates' in Column

Tags: excel, date, grouping

I have a Excel pivot table with Count of Dates. How can I group the dates together by Months?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to your table that returns the month using

=TEXT(A1,"mmmm")

Then you can add this field to your pivot table to group.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any of the column headings for the contextual menu.  Select "Group." Change the group by setting to months.